in vite ts environment when i using lucid react showing this error Module '"lucide-react"' has no exported member 'Workflow'.ts(2305)
for every icon import from the lucid react showing same error and its in typescripts environment.
Module '"lucide-react"' has no exported member 'LayoutDashboard'.ts(2305)
import LayoutDashboard

Your question is difficult to answer without more debugging details. Please add any relevant code and console output as code-fenced text, as well as providing any other relevant information.
